# Why does my jQuery script only begin to start working on 2nd, 3rd, etc. runs, but not on the first run?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple database search script that displays a list of search results as a user types in the search field. The script works fine except that it only begins working after the user types the second letter. I want it to start working when the user enters the first letter in a search query. For example, if I am searching for "dolls", then when the user types the letter "d" into the search field I want the search results to appear. Currently, this only begins to happen after the user has entered "do". Please give me any suggestions you may have.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
    var index = -1;
    $(document).on('keyup','#searchField',function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 38){ // up arrow
            index = (index == 0) ? 0 : index - 1;
            $('tr.search_row').removeClass('highlight_color');
            $('tr.search_row:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('highlight_color');
            return false;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 40){ // down arrow
            index = (index + 1 >= $('tr.search_row').length) ? $('tr.search_row').length - 1 : index + 1;
            $('tr.search_row').removeClass('highlight_color');
            $('tr.search_row:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('highlight_color');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var str = $('#searchField').val();
            searchScript(str);
        }
        index = -1;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: you probably should use $(document ).ready() function.

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is the same as `$(function(){})`

Comment: use keydown or keypress :)

Answer (score 0):

U can use

.bind("change keyup input",function() { });

http://solicitingfame.com/2011/11/09/jquery-keyup-vs-bind/

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to see the the query getting called on the first letter itself. I'm suspecting that the problem might be in the searchScript function. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7qXj/).

```
 Post more details about the searchScript function if you are still seeing the error.
```